# How to change the 'Today' button label in primeng calendar

Tags: angular, primeng

[image: primeng calendar]

I am using priming version 7.1.3. In that I'm using p-calendar and in that if I specify showButtonBar="true" then I am getting today and clear buttons. I need to change the label of the Today button. How can I achieve that?

.html

```
 <div [formGroup]="plf.cueForm">
   <p-calendar 
   #myCalendar 
   [dataType]="'string'" 
   (onTodayClick)="onTodayClick($event)" 
   formControlName="{{itemId}}"  
   [timeOnly]="true" 
   [placeholder]="'HH:MI'" 
   [showIcon]="true" 
   showButtonBar="true"
   appendTo="body"
   icon="fa fa-calendar"></p-calendar>
  </div>
```

Comment: Have you tried setting locale @Input? e.g [locale]="pt" in the calendar?

Comment: @Isha Add the code you tried and current code of the html file

Comment: Even if the calendar/date picker doesn't consent you to change the text you can hide the default text by CSS then put a text via CSS pre/post content

Comment: @alessandro can u plz tell me how to do that in css ?

Comment: @Allabakash check my html i have edited

Comment: You should be able to change the text of the "Today" button using the locale property as @DiegoVictordeJesus pointed out. Look under ´Localization´ on the documentation

Comment: i used that [locale]="tr" throwing me error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can change the text of buttons today/clear using **locale** attribute.

So code look like this,

```
<p-calendar 
   #myCalendar 
   [dataType]="'string'" 
   (onTodayClick)="onTodayClick($event)" 
   [(ngModel)]="value"  
   [timeOnly]="true" 
   [placeholder]="'HH:MI'" 
   [showIcon]="true" 
   showButtonBar="true"
   appendTo="body"
   icon="fa fa-calendar"
   [locale]="en"></p-calendar>
```

---

```
ngOnInit() {  

    this.en = {
      firstDayOfWeek: 0,
      dayNames: ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"],
      dayNamesShort: ["Sun", "Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat"],
      dayNamesMin: ["Su", "Mo", "Tu", "We", "Th", "Fr", "Sa"],
      monthNames: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"],
      today: 'Custom Today',
      clear: 'Clear it !!!'
    };
  }
```

Here is the demo - https://stackblitz.com/edit/prime-ng-calendar-sysnhm
Hope this helps

Comment: This solution is now deprecated